# Passing a variable to ng-container element

Tags: angular, ionic3, angular5

I have a switch case with duplicated html code so I want to reduce this by using `ng-container` like below:

```
<div *ngSwitchCase="competences">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="commonOsiCatalogInfoContainer"></ng-container>
</div>
```

And here is the ng-template:

```
<ng-template #commonOsiCatalogInfoContainer>
    <osi-catalog-info-container>
        <div header>
            {{ veld.titel }}
        </div>
        <div body>
            <li *ngFor="let blok of veld.waarde">
                <div class="s-margin-b">
                    <osi-li-h>{{ blok.toets_omschrijving }}</osi-li-h>
                </div>
                <ion-row *ngFor="let _veld of blok.velden" class="s-margin-b">
                    <ion-col col-auto class="work-form-title-col">
                        <osi-h4>{{_veld.titel}}</osi-h4>
                        <osi-li-body class="osi-black-87 d-block"><b>{{_veld.waarde}}</b></osi-li-body>
                    </ion-col>
                </ion-row>
            </li>
        </div>
    </osi-catalog-info-container>
</ng-template>
```

The only thing that differs is the `osi-li-h` value in some cases it is `blok.title` how can I make this `osi-li-h` dynamic in the `ng-template`?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a context to your ngTemplate like mentioned in this documentation
https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet

You can supply your context in either of the two approches

```
<div *ngSwitchCase="Field.FIELD_NAME_COMPETENCES">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="commonOsiCatalogInfoContainer; context: contextExp"></ng-container>
</div>
```

or by using ngTemplate directly like

```
<div *ngSwitchCase="Field.FIELD_NAME_COMPETENCES">
    <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="commonOsiCatalogInfoContainer [ngTemplateOutletContext]="contextExp"></ng-template>
</div>
```

in both the above examples `contextExp` is nothing but a JSON object.

Then you may use the passed on context properties directly inside your template like

```
<ng-template #commonOsiCatalogInfoContainer let-myIdentifier="JSON_PROPERTY">
    <osi-catalog-info-container>

<div *ngIf="myIdentifier == 'something'"></div>

    </osi-catalog-info-container>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a context object to ng-container and pass the value to your template.

As per [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet):

> You can attach a context object to the EmbeddedViewRef by setting [ngTemplateOutletContext]. [ngTemplateOutletContext] should be an object, the object's keys will be available for binding by the local template let declarations.

Inside your template, you have to do this:

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="eng; context: myContext"></ng-container>
<ng-template #eng let-name><span>Hello {{name}}!</span></ng-template>
```

Comment: and how can I use this in my case as the object properties differ from each other to select the right value?